# How to go to the last match of a Vim search pattern

Tags: regex, vim

In a line, how can Vim match only the last occurrence of a search pattern? Sort of like non-greedy, but from beginning.

e.g. In the following line, I want to match `Twinkle little star` (highlighted in bold):

> Twinkle blah Twinkle blah blah **Twinkle little star**.

I tried negative lookahead like the following, but it is matching the full line:

```
Twinkle.*\(Twinkle\)\@!$
```

Comment: So... You want to search for everything between the last occurrence of Twinkle to the end of the line?  It's hard to tell from the example you've provided.

Comment: Yes, I want to match from the last occurrence of Twinkle to the end end of the line. Acheong87 has given correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape your parentheses and add a wildcard match before the anchor:

```
Twinkle\(.*Twinkle\)\@!.*$
       ^          ^    ^^
```

Comment: No, that also is not working. Vim is still matching full line.

Comment: Oops, put the first wildcard string within the parentheses. Edited.

Comment: A shorter version: `/\v(Twinkle)(.*\1)@!.*`

Answer (score 2):

```
/\v.*\zsTwinkle.*
```

- ".*" greedily matches everything, backtracking on failure to match less (and potentially nothing)
- "\zs" sets "start of match", useful for substitutions and cursor placement
- the rest is what you want to match

Use ":set incsearch", load up some text into a buffer, and start typing the pattern to see how it's applied.

For example, a buffer:

```
Twinkle brightly little star
Twinkle brightly, Twinkle brightly little star
```

And substitution:

```
:%s/\v.*\zsTwinkle /&extra /
```

Gives:

```
Twinkle extra brightly little star
Twinkle brightly, Twinkle extra brightly little star
```